# How to split sentence to words with regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

"She's so nice!" -> ["she","'","s","so","nice","!"]
I want to split sentence like this!
so I wrote the code, but It includes white space!
How to make code only using regular expression?

```
        words = re.findall('\W+|\w+')
```

-> ["she", "'","s", " ", "so", " ", "nice", "!"]

```
        words = [word for word in words if not word.isspace()]
```

Comment: In what way is this not only using regular expressions?

Comment: Whats you actual plan?

Comment: @heemayl I'd like to split every words and special words except white space!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have to remove white space after regular expressions!

Comment: What constitutes a *special word*?

Comment: @heemayl just every words... like ! , ' ?   I can't write down everything. but if I use re.findall('\W+|\w+') this function, I can split it all. but It includes space. like ["she", "'","s"," ", "so", " ", "nice", "!"]

Comment: This is javascript but perhaps you can use it. `function splitString(mystring) {
  return mystring.split(/[ ;,.]+/);
}`

Comment: @Amily you can split the string instead of using findall, but you need to use pypi's `regex` package instead due to zero-width assertions.

Comment: Try this: [`[^\w\s]+|\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/33BiQU/3)

Comment: Try string.findall using this `([^\W_](?:\w|[[:punct:]_-]+(?=\w))*)`

Comment: Do you want to include the punctuated words?  If so, then just `(\S+)\s*` and, in capturing group 1 would be the three words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex**: [`[A-Za-z]+|[^A-Za-z ]`](https://regex101.com/r/6QpJc4/2)

In `[^A-Za-z ]` add chars you don't want to match.

Details:

- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `[^]` Match a single character **NOT** present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `|` Or

**Python code**:

```
text = "She's so nice!"
matches = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|[^A-Za-z ]', text)
```

Output:

```
['She', "'", 's', 'so', 'nice', '!']
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/0EAPzx)

Comment: @Amily What about numbers? How you treat numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Python's `re` module doesn't allow you to split on zero-width assertions. You can use python's [pypi `regex` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) instead (ensuring you specify to use version 1, which properly handles zero-width matches).

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gourWMFWQSk4I1W9WKE4XyEvMzlVUYmrAigIltcrLsjJLNEoUoop1q6JSdKwV4yrUdFU0lEo1lFIy0lML7aFKAtzDQr29Pcz1OTiKijKzCvRqND8/x8A)

```
import regex

s = "She's so nice!"
x = regex.split(r"\s+|\b(?!^|$)", s, flags=regex.VERSION1)

print(x)
```

Output: `['She', "'", 's', 'so', 'nice', '!']`

- `\s+|\b(?!^|$)` Match either of the following options

  - `\s+` Match one or more whitespace characters
  - `\b(?!^|$)` Assert position as a word boundary, but not at the beginning or end of the line